# Do all characters in Don't Starve build the same items?

Tags: dont-starve

When you unlock new characters in Don't Starve they clearly have different strengths, weaknesses and personalities. Do they also build different items, or do they build the same items differently to match their personalities?  (*e.g.* Do they have different raw material requirements?, etc.)

I'm curious about this because of the potential impact on survival strategies this could have.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All characters (except Wickerbottom) craft the same items for the same costs. Certain characters may find certain crafts more or less useful or difficult but they're all the same.

Wickerbottom, the librarian, has two differences when crafting. First, she is the only character who can create books. Second, she can prototype items with a machine one tier lower- for example, she can create alchemy machine items with a science machine, or science machine items anywhere.

Comment: This is an incredibly useful skill, as it means you can craft all the tools, as well as the backpack, before settling down.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the newer characters have special items they can craft:

- As already noted, [Wickerbottom](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Wickerbottom) can craft books
- [Wigfrid](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Wigfrid) can craft copies of her buffed spear and helmet.
- [Webber](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Webber) can create spider dens.

Answer (score 0):

Not all can make the same things, for example, Wilson can't make Spider Dens like Webber, Wolfgang can't make Wickerbottoms books, etc.

Therefore, the answer is no, not every character can make the same items.